# Have a list of strings I want to populate a gui with

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

Basically I have an excel file, and I read into one of my matlab variables a set of strings which are the headers for the columns of the data. Since this excel file is huge and I want to have the option to select which data to analyze at a given time I am hoping to take those strings/headers and have them appear on my gui with some check boxes buttons next to them so that I can pick which ones to work on ( i need the ability to select multiple data columns). This number of headers can change from file to file, so the number of list items and checkboxes will have to change on the gui based on the data file. Any ideas how to accomplish this? I can fill my gui with a bunch of text boxes and radio buttons but then i might end up with some that are empty, or end up with some that are to few, since the data file can have anywhere from 1-50 data columns each with their own header

Alternatively if anyone knows of a better way to have my user choose what data columns to act upon other than a ton of checkboxes, i'd be happy to hear it! This seemed like the most direct approach.

I tried what was suggested and get:

[image: gui output]

The code looks like:

```
[Data,Text] = xlsread('C:\data.csv');
a = Text(:,1);
b = strmatch('Channel Description',a);
Channels = Text(b,:);
[vals{1:numel(Channels,1)}]=deal(false);
foo= uitable('Data',vals,'ColumnEdit', true, 'RowName',Channels);
```

Comment: I would recommend investigating MATLAB's [`uitable`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitable.html) object. You can populate one column with your header names and a second column with checkboxes. The alternative is to create a helper function that generates `x` number of GUI objects (buttons, checkboxes, radio buttons, etc.) and equally spaces them inside a parent object (like a figure window or GUI panel). It's a fun little function to develop but utilizing `uitable()` would be much simpler.

Comment: You get only one checkbox because `numel(Channels,1)`, returns 1. Apologies, that was an error in my example, now fixed.

Comment: @smn gotcha, that works much better. When things are checked off, how do i reference each check box? and then correlate that back to a column number in my data set? the table is populated in order of data, so the columns should remain the same, so if check of volts3 for example i want the 3rd column of data to be worked on and run through a series of actions/analyses.

Comment: @smn I am trying to adapt this http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/109342-uitable-with-logical-cell-checkbox to identify what rows are selected and then use that array to create my new data sets but am haivng some trouble, figuring out what to use get() on. When the table is created what is it's callback now? is it just foo?

Comment: @excelhelp Which version of MATLAB are you using? I have updated my answer with an example which works in R2014b. If you are using get on the handle to uitable (pre-R2014b) then try `cols = get(foo, 'Data')`. You might need to convert to an array `cols = cell2mat(cols)`

Comment: @smn hi, i have a similar question up and am trying to adapt your advice to something slightly bigger. if you have some time, would you mind taking a look and pointing me in the right direction again? sorry for bugging you and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using `uitable`, similar to excaza's comment but using the excel column headers as row names in the table:

```
[~,s,~] = xlsread('excelFile.xlsx', 1, 'A1:ZZ1');
[vals{1:numel(s),1}]   =   deal(false);
foo = uitable('Data', vals, 'ColumnEdit', true, 'RowName', s);
colsToLoad = foo.Data;
```

You will then need to either read the entire table and select columns in MATLAB using `colsToLoad` or loop over `colsToLoad` and read each column separately as `xlsread` does not support non-contiguous ranges.

```
[Data,Text] = xlsread('excelFile.xlsx');
dataToProcess = Data(:,[foo.Data{:}]);
```

Comment: Well my plan was to read in the excel file and then take the header names and make a separate variable array to make the checkboxes from. Where in my gui would i place this code? do i need to draw the table on the panel first and place it in the callback or will this draw it for me as well?

Comment: You can create the `uitable` first, place it where you wish and then set the data and row names once loaded (`foo.Data = ...`, `foo.RowName = ...`). The code above will create a new `uitable` in the current figure.